# Using semantic-ui-react with Webpack in production mode does not work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui, production-environment, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react and I bundle everything using Webpack 3. I have two webpack configs, one for development and the other one for production.

When using semantic-ui-react in development everything works fine. When using in production I am running `webpack -p` inside my script (optimize-minimize) and then it stops working.

The styles are there but if for example I click on drop-down nothing happens. If I remove `-p`, it works again.

What could be a problem and how to fix it?

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: there is no error. I figured it out that -p is doing --optimize-minimize and --define process.env.NODE_ENV = production. If I remove --define part, it works again.
I set my production env like this then 
cross-env NODE_ENV=production

and it works. It's still buggin me why -p doesnt work then.